# Unable to find DOM element with jquery (WordPress, Layer Slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dom, element

There are two elements in Layer slider for WordPress that I am trying to manipulate. But when I try to target either of these two DOM elements I can never actually find them.

Using :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (jQuery('.ls-yourlogo').length) {
    alert('FOUND!!"');
  } else {
    alert('NOT FOUND!');
  }
});
```

I always see "NOT FOUND!", I have verified that the element does exist, although I do not control the creation of this DOM. I can only reference it by "CLASS" and can not add an ID to it.

What would cause these DOM elements to not be found? How can I find them? Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Added "." to class that I was searching for. I had honestly already tired this, I had been working on this for over 18 hours now. I have been unable to find a solution or really anything explaining why I cant select the class.

Comment: the selector is wrong http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an element, not a class. You are missing a period to denote it is a class.

```
jQuery('.ls-yourlogo')
        ^
```

[jQuery class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: That does not change anything for me. It's still unable to be found.

The missing "." is not the issue in this case.

Comment: I know the method works. The main difference between your fiddle and what I am using is: you typed the html element directly in. I can not do that, the code I am trying to manipulate is generated by the Layer Slider plugin for wordpress. 

I'm wondering why out of all the DOM elements, the logo and .ls-inner pretty much the only two I cant touch.

Comment: Than you are reading the element BEFORE it is on the page. That is the problem.

Comment: Read their api, look for the event that says it is ready and hook up to that. If you paid money for it, use their support. lol

Comment: HA! I wish. They don't offer support. Thanks for the advice!